# more elegant code for for if in swift

Tags: swift, if-statement, for-loop

I got a simple code which works and which I am programming in and old fashioned way and I am sure there is a more elegant way of doing this in swift. Here is the code:

```
    var cardsInCompartment1:Int = 0
    var cardsInCompartment2:Int = 0
    for card in cards{
        if card.compartment == 1{
            cardsInCompartment1 += 1
            print(cardsInCompartment1)
        }
        if card.compartment == 2{
            cardsInCompartment2 += 1
            print(cardsInCompartment2)
        }
    }
```

I basically got cards in different compartments and now I want to count how many cards are in each compartment.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `filter` to select the cards you want? Then you can just `count` them:

```
let cardsInCompartment1 = cards.filter { $0.compartment == 1 }.count
let cardsInCompartment2 = cards.filter { $0.compartment == 2 }.count
```

---

If you have a bunch of compartments, you could store the counts in a dictionary:

```
var compartmentCounts = [Int:Int]()

cards.forEach {
    compartmentCounts[$0.compartment] = (compartmentCounts[$0.compartment] ?? 0) + 1
}
```

In this case, the key would be the compartment#, and the value would be the card count. Something like `[1: 32, 2: 42]` if there are 32 and 42 cards in each respective compartment.

Comment: The main issue here is that you're now iterating twice over the list.

Comment: @magni- I don't see that as a big issue unless there's a demonstrable performance problem. It's totally possible the compiler will remove much of the inefficiency… and for a small number of cards, it doesn't really matter. For me, code readability comes first.

Comment: @magni- I updated with a solution that does it in one iteration.

Comment: Totally agree that it doesn't really matter for small lists, but there's an equally (IMO) easy-to-read solution that does it in only one iteration, so why not do it in one? That way it still performs well even if we have twenty different compartments for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var cardsInCompartment1:Int = 0
var cardsInCompartment2:Int = 0
for card in cards {
    (card.compartment == 1) ? (cardsInCompartment1 += 1) : (cardsInCompartment2 += 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store the `cardsInCompartment` as arrays:

```
var cardsInCompartment = [0, 0] // you can add more to this array
```

Then you can just loop through the `cards` and add the values to the array elements:

```
for card in cards {
    cardsInCompartment[card.compartment - 1] += 1
    print(cardsInCompartment[card.compartment - 1])
}
```

Comment: This will print for every card in _cards_

Comment: @nielsbot so what? From the given context, I think he is going to print all the cards anyway.

Comment: fine. that's what the original does. seems unintended.

Answer (score 0):

What about a switch statement? Something like this?

```
var card:Int = 1
var CardsInCompartment:Int = 0
switch (card) {
case 1:
  CardsInCompartment += 1
  print("CardsInCompartment \(CardsInCompartment)")
case 2:
  CardsInCompartment += 2
  print("CardsInCompartment \(CardsInCompartment)")
default:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, use an Array to keep your counts:

```
var counts = [ 0, 0, 0 ] // create an array of integers, where the Ints in the array represent the count of cards in each compartment
cards.forEach { counts[ $0.compartment ] += 1 } // for each card, increment the count in array corresponding to the compartment of the card. (if card.compartment == 1, increment counts[1], and so on

print("cards in compartment 1 \(counts[1])")
print("cards in compartment 2 \(counts[2])")
```

(This assumes your only compartments are integers 1 and 2)

Comment: This is brilliant, but reminds me of the programming in C competitions I used to see now and again that would set a challenge as to who could create the smallest quickest piece of code for a given task. The results often brilliant, and totally cryptic as in very difficult to understand what it was doing, a balance is needed in coding ultimately. No disrespect to nielsbot intended! 12.8k reputation speaks for itself about his abilities and does this two line daemon.

Comment: I will add some comments :)

Comment: Also, I think @Aaron Brager's solution above is more general in the same amount of space.

Answer (score 0):

I like Aaron Brager's idea which counts values into dictionary. I am using reduce to eliminate mutable dictionary outside the 'loop' (more functional)

```
let d = cards.reduce([:]) { (d, card) -> [Int:Int] in
    var d = d
    let s = d[card.compartment] ?? 0
    d[card.compartment] = s + 1
    return d
}
```